# Modbus RTU getting exception 2 (Illegal Data Address) when not querying full block

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I have a sensor that is communicated with via Modbus RTU.  The sensor stores its serial number, encoded as 16-bit integer values, across 8 registers:

> The serial number as ASCII-code is located at read register address
>   30001-30008 (16 bit per address).

(Source: [EE872 User Manual](http://www.epluse.ch/fileadmin/data/product/ee872/BA_EE872_e.pdf), section 5.2.1)

When I use function code `0x04` (read input registers) to read all 8 registers simultaneously, the request **succeeds**.

When I use function code `0x04` to read the registers, either individually, or as a partial group (ex: only the first 7 of 8), the sensor returns an exception code `2` (**illegal data address**).

**Question**

Why would this exception come up, if I am not reading the entire block?

Is there just a poor implementation of Modbus RTU within this sensor?  Or is this standard behavior for Modbus devices?

---

**What I Have Found**

[Modbus error "Illegal Data Address"](https://control.com/forums/threads/modbus-error-illegal-data-address.26652/)

The question in this article seems to hint at a similar issue, but the answer was vague.

---

**Full Code Example**

Input

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import sys
import logging
from collections import namedtuple
from typing import List

from pymodbus.pdu import ModbusResponse
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient
from pymodbus.register_read_message import ReadInputRegistersResponse
from pymodbus.pdu import ExceptionResponse


log = logging.getLogger()
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


ModbusInputReg = namedtuple("ModbusInputRegister", ["name", "address", "value"])

serial_num = ModbusInputReg("serial number", 0x0, None)

PORT = "COM6"
BAUD_RATE = 9600
SLAVE_ADDR = 1


def construct_serial_num(serial_num_arr: List[int]) -> str:
    str_ = ""
    for num in serial_num_arr:
        if num == 0:
            continue
        str_ += bytes.fromhex(f"{num:x}").decode("utf-8")
    return str_


modbus_client = ModbusSerialClient(
    method="rtu",
    port=PORT,
    baudrate=BAUD_RATE,
    strict=False,  # I found CO2 sensor fails if True
)
modbus_client.connect()

COUNT_1 = 7
encoded_sn_1 = modbus_client.read_input_registers(
    address=serial_num.address, count=COUNT_1, unit=SLAVE_ADDR
)  # type: ExceptionResponse
print(f"\nencoded_sn_1 = {encoded_sn_1}.")
print(f"exception code = {encoded_sn_1.exception_code}.\n")

COUNT_2 = 8
encoded_sn_2 = modbus_client.read_input_registers(
    address=serial_num.address, count=COUNT_2, unit=SLAVE_ADDR
)  # type: ReadInputRegistersResponse
print(f"\nencoded_sn_2 = {encoded_sn_2}.")
serial_num = construct_serial_num(encoded_sn_2.registers)
print(f"decoded serial number = {serial_num}.")
```

Output

```
Current transaction state - IDLE
Running transaction 1
SEND: 0x1 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x7 0xb1 0xc8
New Transaction state 'SENDING'
Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
RECV: 0x1 0x84 0x2 0xc2 0xc1
Getting Frame - 0x84 0x2
Factory Response[132]
Frame advanced, resetting header!!
Adding transaction 1
Getting transaction 1
Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'

encoded_sn_1 = Exception Response(132, 4, IllegalAddress).
exception code = 2.

Current transaction state - TRANSACTION_COMPLETE
Running transaction 2
SEND: 0x1 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x8 0xf1 0xcc
Changing state to IDLE - Last Frame End - 1580942727.093152, Current Time stamp - 1580942727.093152
Waiting for 3.5 char before next send - 4.01 ms
New Transaction state 'SENDING'
Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
RECV: 0x1 0x4 0x10 0x31 0x39 0x35 0x30 0x31 0x38 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x32 0x36 0x42 0x32 0x0 0x0 0x7b 0xd4
Getting Frame - 0x4 0x10 0x31 0x39 0x35 0x30 0x31 0x38 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x32 0x36 0x42 0x32 0x0 0x0
Factory Response[ReadInputRegistersResponse: 4]
Frame advanced, resetting header!!
Adding transaction 1
Getting transaction 1
Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'

encoded_sn_2 = ReadRegisterResponse (8).
decoded serial number = 195018000026B2.
```

---

**Device Specifics**

- Device: E+E Elektronik's CO2 sensor, series [EE872](http://www.epluse.ch/en/products/co2-measurement/co2-sensor/ee872/)
- Modbus RTU, `9600/8-N-1`, slave 1
- [User Manual](http://www.epluse.ch/fileadmin/data/product/ee872/BA_EE872_e.pdf) (section 5.2 contains Modbus RTU information)
- Device is plugged into Windows machine that I run this Python script

**Packages**

I am using Python 3.6 on Windows 10.

```py
pymodbus==2.3.0
```

---

Aside: sorry for the verbosity of this question, I just wanted to make sure I dispelled potential questions in advance.

Comment: The error means the slave is not configured to reply block wise but not at individual register levels.